# Exception has occurred. _Exception (Exception: Error reading PDF!) on loading pdf from url

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm facing these errors

- Exception has occurred. _Exception (Exception: Error reading PDF!) on loading pdf from url
- and failed to parse assets on load pdf form assets

> This is my Code

---

```
  loadfile() async {
    document = await PDFDocument.fromURL(
        'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');

    setState(() {
      document = document;
    });
  }
```

```
      body: Center(child: PDFViewer(document: document)),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

_launchURL() async {
 const url = 'https://flutter.dev/exapmle.pdf';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
await launch(url);
 } else {
throw 'Could not launch $url';
 }
}
```

You can use this without downloading file,open from URL using the package : url_launcher

Comment: I'm using  flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer